# Вывод div блока в определенное время

Tags: html

Если знаете подскажите какой код будет на html странице показывать div блок только с 20:40 до 22:00 по Киеву каждый день, Заранее спасибо (если можно пример кода или шаблон)

Comment: На html это невозможно сделать. Какой язык программирования  вы используйте?

Comment: в html же можно php вставить?

Comment: Да, можно вставить в html.

Comment: `Если знаете подскажите какой код будет` - Если все верно написать, код будет очень красивый...

Answer (score 4):

Если это php, то смотрите время на сервере и выводите нужный блок. Если это js, то скрипт смотрит время на компе посетителя и делает блок видимым.

Код на PHP (как вариант).

```
// текущее время ЧЧММ
$this_hour_minute = date("Hi");

// сравнение и вывод
if ($this_hour_minute > 2039 and $this_hour_minute < 2200)
{
    echo '<div>БЛОК ДЛЯ ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ</div>';
}
```

Comment: "Если это php, то смотрите время на сервере и выводите нужный блок. "   если можно пример кода скиньте

Comment: Добавил пример.

Comment: Спасибо. А еще вопрос - возможно ли автоматически обновлять страницу на которой будет этот код также в заданное время. Я нашел только это  // <?php

    header("refresh: 3;");
?>     как задать время для refresh в 22 часа по серверу    Спасибо заранее за ответ

Comment: Для таких вещей используется cron на сервере. Обычно в панели управления сервером называется Планировщиком заданий. В нём создаёте задание. Есть нюансы, которые зависят от самой панели и сервера, поэтому лучше обратиться к справке хостера или в его техподдержку. Они помогут. Если это локально, то, например в Open Server, в настройках тоже есть свой планировщик заданий.

Comment: мне надо чтобы перезагрузка браузера происходила в заданное время, а хостер говорить что с помощью cron это нельзя сделать

Comment: Вы не браузер обновляете в определенное время (22 часа), а выполняете какой-то php-скрипт. Вот для этого крон и используется. Если вы хотите обновить страницу, которая уже открыта в браузере пользователя, то наверное единственный способ — это использовать js-скрипт, который будет брать время компа, часовой пояс, вычислять киевское время и по нужному условию делать обновление страницы. При том, придется повесить куку-флаг, иначе перезагрузка войдет в цикл.